# Geometric Line representing external core face or internal core face of a wall in Revit API

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I would like to extract the line segment that represents a wall in plan view for each of the various layers of a wall.

What mechanism exist in the Revit API to allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can get exactly what you want - but here is my thought... You need to use the Parts functionality (check out the PartUtils class which has many static methods to do the work) to split your wall into parts based on its layers. Once you have the layers, you'll be able to extract face geometry from the layers, and from there decide how you want to project/extract the face points onto the plane you're interested in.

Jeremy Tammik has a couple of relevant blog posts on this:

- http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/10/retrieving-detailed-wall-layer-geometry.html

  - http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/identifying-wall-compound-layers-and-parts.html

Good Luck,
Matt